# Handle validation error messages to view rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, view, error-handling

I have implemented simple form to register users with captcha in it. 
Everything is working fine, but I could not able to manage validation errors to be shown on views, it looks easy but I guess I am missing some points here. 
here is my model

```
class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
    apply_simple_captcha :message => "The secret Image and code were different", :add_to_base => true
    validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/ , :message => "Invalid Email Format"
end
```

Then this my view

```
<%= form_for(@email, url: emails_new_path) do |f| %>
<div class="field">
<%= f.text_field :email, placeholder: "Enter Email" %>
</div>
<%= show_simple_captcha(:email=>"email", :label => "Human   Authentication", :placeholder => "Enter the code") %>
<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<%= @email.errors.full_messages.first if @email.errors.any? %>
<% end %>
```

Controller

```
class EmailsController < ApplicationController
   def new
    @email = Email.new(user_params)
    if !user_params.nil?
      if simple_captcha_valid?
        puts "Right captcha"
        @email.save!
        if @email.save
          flash[:success] = "Thanks! We will be in touch soon!"
          redirect_to :action => 'new'
        else
          flash[:success] = "Invalid Emails"
          render :action => 'new'
        end
        else
        puts "Wrong captcha"
        flash[:success] = "Wrong Emails"
      end
    end
  end

  def user_params
     params.require(:email).permit(:email) if params[:email]
  end

end
```

So the question is how can I manage messages both from model and controller to be shown on view on button click. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `save_with_captcha` for validation like:

`@email = Email.new(user_params)`

`if @email.save_with_captcha`

`puts "Right captcha"`

`else`

`puts "error with captcha"`

`end`